# how to deploy a program using clients like @solana/web3.js, @project-serum/anchor

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang, anchor-client, anchor-program

I dont want to deploy a program using cli or solana playground ide
I want to deploy a program using clients packages of solana/web3.js, @project-serum/anchor, or any other packages

can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A program on Solana is just an account whose data happens to be bytecode, and whose `executable` flag is set to `true`.

To deploy programs, the Solana CLI sends instructions to the [*System Program*](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/1.14.3/solana_sdk/system_instruction/enum.SystemInstruction.html) and the [*BPF Upgradeable Loader Program*](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/1.14.3/solana_sdk/loader_upgradeable_instruction/enum.UpgradeableLoaderInstruction.html).

Here's an approach you can take:

1. Study [the implementation of the CLI](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/547f07526ba8a88f3c0915b715bcb5e30760129d/cli/src/program.rs#L833-L1058) to see how it uses the System Program to create the account that will become the program, and the BPF Upgradeable Loader Program to initialize, configure, and populate that account.
2. Create a client using `@solana/web3.js` that creates and executes those same instructions in a series of transactions.